# Setting underground belt direction in blueprint

Tags: factorio

Is there a way to set a direction of underground belt while placing ghost image, for construction bots?

When i place ghost images and rotate the item, it simple changes its input face and not the belt movement direction (in or out)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For blueprints, just make sure that you manually place the underground belts in the correct direction first and it should work.
(It worked for me at least on vanilla builds.)
If it does not work, you can try placing a normal belt that follows the direction of the underground belts alongside with the blueprint.

For ghost building, what I did was I always to make sure that the input belt gets build first before placing the output belt.
Because the first underground belt that always gets placed first by the bots will always be the input belt. (And the same applies to player when they place their belts.)

Comment: that is a nice and simple way but how can I restrict bots to place belts before underground belts if I have a big blueprint? Like for example balancers?

Comment: and i have accepted it because it tells me a work around to get it done. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not catch you there. Can you elaborate more on your first question?

Comment: oh actually now that i re-read your answer it explains. You were saying in 2nd para about ghost images not blueprints. I mixed them and got confused. Your answer is explanatory enough thanks.